# update column that is refreshed with data everyday

Tags: sql-server, date, sql-update

I have a table where we append data into daily. The source table doesn't have a date column and I created a date column in the new table so that we can track what data we are adding from the source table everyday using the select convert (date, getdate()) statement.

How do I insert the daily date into the new table from the old column (which doesn't have a date column) so that the correct date is added to the new table everyday. For example:

```
SRC table: data added on 01/01/2016
A B C
1 2 3

SRC table: data added on 01/02/2016
A B C 
4 5 6

SRC table: data added on 01/03/2016
A B C
7 8 9

New Table:
A B C Date
1 2 3 2016-01-01
4 5 6 2016-01-02
7 8 9 2016-01-03
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this, which will set a default value for your date column.  This means whenever you add a row, the date column will pick up the current date:-

```
alter table [New Table]
add constraint defaultvalue
default (convert(date,getdate())) for [date]
```

You could also do this by directly changing the 'Default Value or Binding' property in the visual table designer in SSMS.

Comment: thanks. do i need to add an append statement in the ssis package so that it tells sql to start inserting records from the last row or does it do that by default? For example, on the second day when I am trying to insert records 4,5,6..should i just let the sql task run on its own in an ssis package without an append statement in the beginning?

Comment: This will only work for new records.  You would have to populate anything prior to adding this constraint yourself.

Comment: Just getting my head around this again....the SQL script I provided is something you should run in SSMS to change the definition of the table.  It's not something you run every time as a script.

Comment: Once your SSIS package updates the rows, the default will then populate automatically.

Comment: oh thats a very good solution, much better than adding a convert(date,getdate()) in the insert to statement in the new table in SSIS!

Comment: Yes, constraints are automagic and you can override them, if required. And, if your goal is to just tag when something was INSERTED, they are low overhead.